# Loop selenium python

Tags: python, loops, selenium

I'm trying to do this thing, I have a list of elements all equal, but if i create a loop that have to click on all the element it stops at the first one and clicking it infinite times, i don0t know how to pass to the next becouse the doesn't have difference on click or in other way. What can i do?

This is the loop

```
a=0
while a < 3:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/span/section/main/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[2]/section[3]/form/textarea").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea._bilrf").send_keys("hi!", Keys.ENTER)
a += 1
```

```html
<section class="_km7ip _ti7l3 "><form class="_b6i0l"><textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..." placeholder="Aggiungi un commento..." class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea></form></section>
<section class="_km7ip _ti7l3 "><form class="_b6i0l"><textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..." placeholder="Aggiungi un commento..." class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea></form></section>
<section class="_km7ip _ti7l3 "><form class="_b6i0l"><textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..." placeholder="Aggiungi un commento..." class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea></form></section>
<section class="_km7ip _ti7l3 "><form class="_b6i0l"><textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..." placeholder="Aggiungi un commento..." class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea></form></section>
<section class="_km7ip _ti7l3 "><form class="_b6i0l"><textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..." placeholder="Aggiungi un commento..." class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea></form></section>
<section class="_km7ip _ti7l3 "><form class="_b6i0l"><textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..." placeholder="Aggiungi un commento..." class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea></form></section>
<section class="_km7ip _ti7l3 "><form class="_b6i0l"><textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..." placeholder="Aggiungi un commento..." class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea></form></section>
```

And this the element

`<form class="_b6i0l"><textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..." 
placeholder="Aggiungi un commento..." class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" 
autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea></form>`

Comment: Your Python code won't run unless it is indented properly. I think that was pointed out to you in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581741/loop-for-equal-elements).

Comment: i am assuming that you `section` tag has unique class name

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath`?

something like:

```
for e in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/span/section/main/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[2]/section[3]/form/textarea"):
    e.click()
```

Documentation:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: i tried but it say `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

Comment: i wrote this `commenti = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text ("Commenta")` `for e in commenti:
        e.click ()`